# Displaying results in a table horizontally

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 and trying to figure out how to get some results to align themselves horizontally in a table and not vertically. See my [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/EfRF2ekQyw)

I want to achieve something like this:

```
Peter| Orange, banana, apple
John | Apple, orange
Mary |
Sam  | Orange
```

But I keep getting this:

```
    Peter| 
    Orange, 
    banana, 
    apple
    John | 
    Apple, 
    orange
    Mary |
    Sam  | 
    Orange
```

The html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">


<br>


<span class="label label-default\">table</span>

<h2>Table 2</h2>
<table><tbody><tr><td><span class="label label-default">Mary</span></td></tr><tr><td><span class="label label-success"></span></td></tr></tbody></table><table><tbody><tr><td><span class="label label-default">John</span></td></tr><tr><td><span class="label label-success">banana</span></td></tr></tbody></table><table><tbody><tr><td><span class="label label-default">Peter</span></td></tr><tr><td><span class="label label-success">orange</span></td></tr><tr><td><span class="label label-success">orange</span></td></tr></tbody></table><table><tbody><tr><td><span class="label label-default">Sue</span></td></tr><tr><td><span class="label label-success">orange</span></td></tr><tr><td><span class="label label-success">apple</span></td></tr></tbody></table>

 </div> <!-- /col.8 -->
</div><!-- /center-block -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `<tr></tr>` creates new rows you need to remove those between the cells within each table

```
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="label label-default">Mary</span>
      </td>
      <!-- removed the close and start "tr" tag from here  -->
      <td>
        <span class="label label-success"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

And there is really no need to make multiple tables, so your code could look like this

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="label label-default\">table</span>
    <h2>Table 2</h2>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span class="label label-default">Mary</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span class="label label-success"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span class="label label-default">John</span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="label label-success">banana</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="label label-default">Peter</span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="label label-success">orange</span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="label label-success">orange</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- /col.8 -->
  </div>
  <!-- /center-block -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to achieved something like this?

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">


<br>


<span class="label label-default\">table</span>

<h2>Table 2</h2>
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><span class="label label-default">Mary</span></td>
     
         <td><span class="label label-success">data</span></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><span class="label label-default">John</span></td>
   
         <td><span class="label label-success">banana</span></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><span class="label label-default">Peter</span></td>
   
         <td><span class="label label-success">orange</span></td>
    
         <td><span class="label label-success">orange</span></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><span class="label label-default">Sue</span></td>
     
         <td><span class="label label-success">orange</span></td>
   
         <td><span class="label label-success">apple</span></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>


 </div> <!-- /col.8 -->
</div><!-- /center-block -->
```